# What are the risks of giving a VM more than 50% of my RAM?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I have recently downloaded Windows 8 which I want to test in 
VirtualBox. I have 2.00 (1.80 GB usable) RAM, but Windows 8 requires 1.5 GB RAM on a virtual disk, when I try it by allotting 1 Gb of RAM it became stuck on the setup.

Is there any problem if I give Windows 8 on virtual disk more than 50% (1.5 GB) of my RAM? Can I ignore the alert VirtualBox gives me and continue at my own risk?

Comment: Try VirtualBox on Ubuntu, if will still warn you (but you will have all 2GB ram usable), but you can continue as Ubuntu takes less ram than Windows and (-Ubuntu-) can still run perfectly on 512MB (0.5GB) Ram.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Watching your memory usage / swapping should be fine.

Comment: This is common sense, no?

Comment: @AkshatMittal I'm not sure switching operating systems just to improve try Win8 out in a VM is a very practical recommendation.

Comment: Also, if you can slot more RAM into your computer, just buy as much as you can. (The single most annoying thing about ultrabooks is that none of them support over 4GB.) Never swapping is the next best performance improvement you can get after switching to a SSD, and cheaper to boot.

Comment: @millimoose Pretty much, the author of the post specified that he has Ubuntu already setup on the same machine, so I just suggested to try the VM in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alert is mostly a recommendation, a guideline that should be "good enough" for most people. If you don't leave enough memory free to the host OS it will have to start swapping and perform slowly. This might in turn, paradoxically slow down your virtual machine, since it needs resources from the host OS as well.

There's really no *harm*, per se, in ignoring the warning, feel free to experiment. If, while using (mostly) the VM, you feel your system get choppy and unresponsive, and the guest OS still has enough memory free, consider giving the virtual machine less RAM.

Answer (score 1):

There are no risks involved in running a very memory hungry application (a virtual box) that consumes 50 or more percent of your total memory.